# Graph theory path notation

Tags: graph-theory, notation

Is the following notation appropriate for denoting a path within a graph?

$P=\{ab, bc, ca, cd, da\}$

Comment: My recommendation: use the definition and notation for a *walk* in [Diestel: *Graph Theory*, Fifth Edition, p. 10]. What you asked about is a walk which is **not** a path (according to the terminology in op. cit., which is quite in tune with usual contemporary graph-theoretic terminology, and has very clean notation and presentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not good notation.

First a path is a *sequence* of edges, not a *set* of edges. This allows for the path to pass over an edge more than once, which is certainly allowable in the definition of a path in a graph.

Second, even if one presumes that you are mis-using set notation, and that your intention was indeed to list the edges one after another, in that case you have not listed the edges in order and in the correct orientation along the path, making it that much harder for the reader to parse your path. For example, it appears from your notation that $ca$ is followed on the path by $cd$ which is clearly impossible because they do not meet end to end, meaning that terminal vertex $a$ of the edge $ca$ does not match the initial vertex $c$ of the next edge $cd$.

I would suggest a more geometric notation like 
$$P = ab * bc * ca * ad * dc
$$
Notice that I interchanged the last two edges in your list, *and* I reversed each of their orientations.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, I can see what's wrong with it now. What is the significance of the asterisks? What if I replace the set brackets with regular brackets and make sure that the edges are ordered logically, for example $P=(ab, bc, ca, ad, dc)$, would that still be incorrect?

Comment: That would be fine. The asterisk is not necessary, but it is a helpful reminder that you are not allowed to concatenate edges without checking something (namely, the terminal vertex of the preceding edge equals the initial endpoint of the next edge). Formally the asterisk is the "concatenation" operator sometimes used in topology.

Comment: To nitpick a bit: the definition 'path'='sequence of edges' is not recommendable in graph theory. When doing formal proofs, one absolutely wants to have one-vertex paths available. Otherwise, constructing proofs is more difficult. And the above definition does not proved one-vertex paths: if there is one edge, then there are two vertices, and even if you allow empty sequences of edges, you still do not get a one-vertex path. In my opinion the OP should *not* learn to use this definition, rather should adopt the definition in [Diestel, Graph Theory, Fifth Edition, Section 1.3]

Comment: Also, the "allows for the path to pass over an edge" clashes with the usual convention in Graph Theory: 'walk':'alternating sequence of vertices and edges, with arbitrary repetitions allowed', 'trail':'such a sequence, with vertex-repetitions but no edge-repetitions allowed', 'path':'such a sequence, but no repetitions whatsoever'.

Comment: Those are good conventions too, although they are not necessarily the most useful in every context where graphs are studied, such as in topology. Which was why I did not offer any definitions to the OP, just a minimal improvement to the OP's notational conventions.

Comment: Paths can also be written *as a sequence of vertices* unless you allow a multigraph.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't, insofar you are using {set} brackets there. If this is not intended, use (normal) brackets to avoid confusion. In a set, the order of elements is not given, and therefore your path wouldn't be well defined in most if not all cases.